# Struggling with applying PBR textures to object: grey texture instead of the PBR

Tags: texturing, pbr

I have downloaded a glass PBR from CGAXIS (blender format), opened it in Blender and tried to apply it to a model I created.
As you can see in the screenshot, it appears gray and opaque, not transparent as glass.

I have added sunlight; and I am in Eevee. The node set up looks correct.  The material preview looks fine, but grey as well (see picture).

The texture I downloaded is this one: https://cgaxis.com/product/dirty-glass-pbr-texture/

I must be missing very basic  something but what?

[image]

Edit: new image[image]

Comment: From this PBR material you only need the *Roughness* map. *Displacement* only works in *Cycles*, not in *Eevee*. You can remove these nodes, Most of the other maps are "empty", e.g. *Metallic* is pure black (=0) because it's glass. The base color map also looks pure grey. Same for *Emission*, *Height*, *Normal*, etc. Just set the values (Metallic=0, etc) in the *Principled BSDF*. In the end, you just need to set the base color, use the *Roughness* image texture, and set *Transmission* to 1. Then you can add a little transparency (*Alpha* value < 1), see SlickRed's answer for the settings.

Comment: Hello, thank you this helped a lot with this specific texture; but I am encountering similar issues with other materials (see edited post with new picture of blue texture). How can I get the right look from the get go? When I watch tutorials they just use node wrangled and it looks perfect. In my case there is always something that doesn't look right and I don't know how to fix it. Am I missing something?  @Blunder

Comment: Hi. Just to clarify: Do you want to create a blue-tinted glass flower? The nodes are hard to see in the image that you posted. But when you look at the material preview image on the right side, you see that it has some displacement. But the linked PBR material has no displacement because the height and normal map are "flat". Furthermore, you can see the preview looks metallic. But the PBR material's metallic map is black (=0). So I wonder what have you plugged into this slot? Last but not least, you have still set *Transmission* of the P.BSDF to 0.

Comment: For a glass shader, set *Metallic* of the *Principled BSDF* node to 0 and *Transmission* to 1. Use a very light blue color and the *Roughness* image texture. I also would remove the displacement nodes. Glass is usually flat, isn't it? If you still want to use displacement then keep in mind this requires a clean mesh with enough geometry to deform. My guess is, that your flower is made of curves (SVG import?). This creates a very bad triangulated mesh. This is the reason why the displacement of the flower looks different than the displacement of the material preview sphere.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a problem with the Blend Mode in the material settings.

When using transparency with the Eevee engine (not required in Cycles), it is necessary to change this setting from Opaque to Alpha Blend. I believe Alpha Hashed works as well, although I'm not sure about the difference between the two.

[image]

As a side note, it's often a good idea to turn on Screen Space Refractions as well.

Comment: Transparency is needed when you have 2 or more glass objects behind each other. Else Eevee shows only the one in the foreground and hides the others. The option *Show Backface* (in the [documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/eevee/materials/settings.html?highlight=show+backside#sorting-problem)) *Show Backside* should be disabled when you use *Alpha Blend*. Otherwise, you will get strange effects (see "Sorting Problem"). Last but not least, it's recommended to use an HDRI in the *World Settings*. The default is grey color and your model will look sad and grey.

Comment: Appreciate the extra details, thank you sir!